# Visual Studio: Cannot connect to localhost

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a car project that i'm working on in visual studio but after setting it up at my school, I had to come home to work on it. However now i'm running into this error when I try to run the program:

```
This localhost page can’t be found
No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:62915/api/values
```

My question is, how do I get my program to run or connect locally to my machine? I already went through setting up a local DB and a local server.

Comment: that looks like an IIS Express port. Are you using Visual Studio locally?

Comment: You have not provided enough information. Are you trying to run or access a REST service?

Comment: I have a REST service running but it still doesn't find my local. If this question is too narrow, perhaps someone can point me towards a tutorial I don't know about?

Answer (score 1):

*Note: This answer is under the assumption that you're using Windows 10*

It sounds like you've taken a copy of the solution which is designed to run locally in IIS Express, but then you've ran it and it can't find IIS Express.

You'll have to go to

**Start Menu** >> **"Turns Windows Features on or off"** >> *Select* **"Internet Information Services"**

You may have to restart, but with IIS turned on you should be able to access your application